# ruby, how can I remove a space at the end with gsub?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

This removes all spaces:

```
irb(main):021:0> 'gff gf ggfgfg '.gsub(' ','')
=> "gffgfggfgfg"
```

but I want just to remove the space at the end,

something like

```
irb(main):023:0>  'gff gf ggfgfg '.gsub([*' '$],'')
```

but I get:

```
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):25: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ']'
'gff gf ggfgfg '.gsub([*' '$],'')
                            ^
    from (irb):25
    from :0
                           ^
    (irb):23: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end
    'gff gf ggfgfg '.gsub(^' ','')
                               ^
        from (irb):23
        from :0
```

n.b. I can't use truncate, trim and other rails helpers.

Comment: -1 Did you try fixing the syntax error?

Comment: Yes Andrew I tried many variations and finally decided to post my question with at least the code I had even though it included the syntax error.  Folks frequently say 'did you try something, anything?' so I wanted to show that I did. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a regular expression which matches only whitespace at the end of the string:

```ruby
'foo bar '.gsub(/\s+$/,'') # => "foo bar"
```

There is also [`rstrip` and `rstrip!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rstrip):

```ruby
'foo bar '.rstrip # => "foo bar"
```

Comment: +1, that's what I would do.  Familiar with this regex, because it's one of the first things I do in vim when i crack open some one else's old nasty code I have to refactor :%s/\s\+$//g, and this one too :%s/\t/  /g.

Comment: +1 & Accept. Yes and yes for the `rstrip` and `rstrip!`  Thanks!

Comment: attention: strip etc kill WHITESPACE, thus also TAB!

Answer (score 6):

There's also [`String#rstrip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rstrip), which isn't a Rails thing:

```
'  foo bar   '.rstrip # => "  foo bar"
```

There's a self-modifying version `rstrip!`, as well as `lstrip`(`!`) for leading space and `strip`(`!`) for both.

Comment: Thx, but only trailing for this question.